# Setup a form entity flield with query builder results

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

Hello everyone I need your help in this issue, the point is:

I have two related entities "Cargo" and "CatVal", see next figure:

```
CARGO (Key: ShipCargoId)   CATVAL (Key: CatValId)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ShipCargoId + CargoId +  +CatValId + CatValDesc +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     3       +     1   +  +    1    + Cargo 1    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Ok, in this figure note these related entities have a relation between ShipCargoId.CargoId and CatVal.CatValId and these relation es configure in my Entity file how OneToMany relation from CatVal To Cargo as you can see at next:

```
namespace OLO\CargoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Cargo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shipcargos")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\CargoRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Cargo
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatVal", inversedBy="cargos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CargoId", referencedColumnName="CatValId")
 */
protected $cargoId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ShipCargoId", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $shipCargoId;

 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getShipCargoId()
{
    return $this->shipCargoId;
}

/**
 * Set cargoId
 *
 * @param \OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatVal $cargoId
 * @return Cargo
 */
public function setCargoId(\OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatVal $cargoId = null)
{
    $this->cargoId = $cargoId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cargoId
 *
 * @return \OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatVal 
 */
public function getCargoId()
{
    return $this->cargoId;
}

}

namespace OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * CatVal
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="catval")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatValRepository")
 */
  class CatVal
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\Cargo", 
    mappedBy="cargoId")
 */
protected $cargos;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CatValId", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $catValId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CatValDesc", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $catValDesc;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->cargos = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get catValId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCatValId()
{
    return $this->catValId;
}

/**
 * Set catValDesc
 *
 * @param string $catValDesc
 * @return CatVal
 */
public function setCatValDesc($catValDesc)
{
    $this->catValDesc = $catValDesc;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get catValDesc
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCatValDesc()
{
    return $this->catValDesc;
}

/**
 * Add cargos
 *
 * @param \OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\Cargo $cargos
 * @return CatVal
 */
public function addCargo(\OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\Cargo $cargos)
{
    $this->cargos[] = $cargos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove cargos
 *
 * @param \OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\Cargo $cargos
 */
public function removeCargo(\OLO\CargoBundle\Entity\Cargo $cargos)
{
    $this->cargos->removeElement($cargos);
}

/**
 * Get cargos
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCargos()
{
    return $this->cargos;
}
}
```

Then, I need to achieve generate a form with entity field which the label be "CatValDesc" and the value be "ShipCargoId"

To achive this I configure a query builder in FormType file, as you can see next:

```
>add('shipCargos', 'entity', array(
                                                'class'  => 'OLOCatalogBundle:CatVal',
                                                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($ShipId){
                                                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                                              ->addSelect('c.shpCargoId','p.catValDesc')
                                                              ->leftJoin('c.cargos', 'p', Join::WITH, 'c.catValId = p.cargoId')
                                                              ->where('p.shipId = :id')
                                                              ->setParameter('id', $ShipId);
                                                },
                                                'choice_label' => 'catValDesc',
        ))
```

But I can't make it work, the error that show me now is:

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 1189   -

 */
public function isScheduledForInsert($entity)
{
    return isset($this->entityInsertions[spl_object_hash($entity)]);
}
/**

 at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 
 to be object, integer given', '/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php', '1189', array('entity' => '45'))

at spl_object_hash ('45')
```

If I change the addSelect for ->addSelect('c','p') to retrieve intities instead integer value, show me this error:

```
Neither the property "shipCargoId" nor one of the methods "getShipCargoId()", "shipCargoId()", "isShipCargoId()", "hasShipCargoId()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "OLO\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatVal".
```

So, any idea how I can make it work like a charm?, best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to select the ID but the entire Entity, the form builder takes the ID for you. Your query builder should be like this:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($ShipId){
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->join('c.cargos', 'cg')
        ->where('cg.shipCargoId = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $ShipId);
},
```

*If I get it right, the shipCargoId is the id of the ship? The CatValId is the primary key of the CatVal entity. By selecting the CatVal Entities you also select the IDs, so you don't need to do that explicitly.*

Comment: Thanks Joris for you help, but in this case the ID is in the entity "Cargo" and the description which i nedd is in other entity "CatVal", how i can perform that?, with these query builder only get the CatVal properties, is not?

Comment: Reading on my smarphone now. Will be back for you later

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again Joris for your answer, let me explain more details about this relational model (I forgot a few coments, sorry my fault): There are three entities "Shipment" / "Cargo" / "CatVal", so one Shipment have many Cargo, then: ShipId = 1 have ShipCargoId = 1,2,3,etc. The ShipId property gone form Shipment entity to Cargo entity like a foreing key. So ShipCargoId is the key of cargo entity

Comment: Then to retrieve the Cargos that belongs to ShipId is necesary this variable $ShipId which i pass to FormType through my CargoController. At this point all worked fine

Comment: And the CatVal entity is a simple reference table or "Catalog" of distinc Cargos that user can choose in the view obviously. So the entity Cargo is related with CatVal entity through cargo.CargoId = catval.CatValId. The property cargo.ShipCargoId can't related with CatVal entity

Comment: In summary, an example may be: Shipment entity: ShipId = 1, Cargo entity: ShipId=1 have ShipCargoId = 3 CargoId=45 and ShipCargoId = 4 CargoId = 32, CatVal entity: CatValId =45 have a CatValDesc = Cargo 1 and CatValId= 32 have a CatValDesc = Cargo 2. As you can see the relation between cargo.CargoId and catval.CatValId is that I need to achieve the descriptions of cargos